# Does printing a string really take O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I was doing an example from Cracking the Coding Interview and I read that executing `System.out.println(prefix);` (where prefix is a String) would take "O(n) time since each character needs to be printed". If a similar print statement was placed inside a O(1) algorithm (e.g. hash table lookup, etc.) would it make the entire algorithm O(n)?

Comment: What's `n`? You need to keep closer track of what `n` is to resolve this.

Comment: @user2357112 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Use_in_computer_science

Comment: @НЛО I think user2357112 means, what is `n` **in this case**. Which I'll elaborate on. :)

Comment: @НЛО N can be the number of iterms in the hash table, or the number of characters in the string. So `println(table[key])` still looks up in the table in O(1) but then println is O(n) (n being number of characters now).

Comment: @duskwuff well, it's obvious that `n` is length of string here: _similar print statement was placed inside a O(1) algorithm_ (@Matt is right)

Comment: @НЛО No, it's not obvious due to the example of a hash-table, where the order of lookups would be proportional to (or in this case not proportional to) the size of the table.

Comment: @Chris how's `println` is not O(n), am I missing something?

Comment: @НЛО `println` is O(n), I'm just saying that in this case it's not obvious the question author is referring to string length as n. In fact I think part of the reason they might not have understood properly is that they are conflating the size of a hash map with the size of strings in a hash map as possible values for n.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When describing the big-O complexity of an algorithm, it is crucial to define what the variables in the expression represent. There may often be several! For instance, looking up an integer in a binary tree, then printing the string associated with that node might be characterized as `O(m + log n)`, where `n` is the number of objects in the tree and `m` is the length of the string.

It is always an error to use a single variable to represent multiple different factors (e.g, both the number of elements in a hash table and their size), and doing so will result in plainly absurd results (e.g, a hash table lookup being `O(n)`).

Comment: "For instance, looking up a string in a binary tree, then printing it might be characterized as `O(m + log n)`" - or `O(m*log(n))`, since string comparisons can take `O(m)` time, and unless your BST is particularly specialized, it probably doesn't have the extra metadata or specialized lookup code to take advantage of earlier comparisons to speed up later ones.

Comment: @user2357112 Perhaps that wasn't the best example! I've adjusted it to remove the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same question from the same example in Cracking the Coding Interview. The line of code being referred is

```
void permutation(String str, String prefix) {
  if (str.length() == 0) {
    System.out.println(prefix)
  } else {
    // some for loop recursive code
  }
}
```

Later in the problem it says
"How long does each function call take?
Executing line 7 takes O9n) time since each character needs to be printed."
Line 7 is in reference to the print statement.

Someone else gave a good explanation from Quora:
https://www.quora.com/What-exactly-is-the-time-complexity-for-System-out-println-in-Java-O-1-or-O-N

> To print anything on the screeen one needs to copy it to the "stdout" file. So when we call System.out.println(), it copies the value of its parameter into the stdout file and we know that copying a string will take O(n) where n is the length of the string.
> Try this.

```
for(int i = 0;i < 100000;++i)  
System.out.println("a");
```

And after that try this.

```
for(int i = 0;i < 100000;++i)  
System.out.println("asdhasdyasiluftyiufhiuasydfujshaskljdaklsdhkajsasdjhakjshakjsfgajskgjfgdsajfgasdkjgadviuasgdfmnasdbfjgsdyjakdhggggggggcjhasdfjkgsjkdfgsdfhgdsfdsfgalsdkjfdhkagsdjkasdjd");
```

> If System.out.println()'s time complexity is O(1) both the statements will take nearly same time otherwise you'll see the difference. :)

So a print statement is O(n) if n is the length of the string. But if you have a hash table lookup, big O would be n if n is the length of the string.